# Getting percentage from count in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table as follows:

```
COL1    COL2    DATETIMESTAMP   CATEGORY1   CATEGORY2
e-12    1101    201408110525    Arts and Entertainment  Television
e-12    1101    201408110525    Arts and Entertainment  Television
e-12    1101    201408110525    Arts and Entertainment  Television
e-12    1101    201408110620    Technology and Computing    Internet Technology
e-12    1101    201408110705    Technology and Computing    Antivirus Software
e-12    1107    201408110510    Business    Advertising
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing
e-12    1109    201408110505    Technology and Computing    Web Search
```

Disregarding COL1 (as they are all the same), for every COL2, there is a combination of the rest of the fields. I managed to get the counts of the repeating combination, resulting in the following:

```
COL1    COL2    DATETIMESTAMP   CATEGORY1   CATEGORY2   COUNT
e-12    1101    201408110525    Arts and Entertainment  Television  3
e-12    1101    201408110620    Technology and Computing    Internet Technology 1
e-12    1101    201408110705    Technology and Computing    Antivirus Software  1
e-12    1107    201408110510    Business    Advertising 1
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing   7
e-12    1109    201408110505    Technology and Computing    Web Search  1
```

How do I turn the count into a percentage of all the combinations per COL2?

I'm sorry I can't better put this in words, but the output should be like this:

```
COL1    COL2    DATETIMESTAMP   CATEGORY1   CATEGORY2   COUNT   PERCENTAGE
e-12    1101    201408110525    Arts and Entertainment  Television  3   60%
e-12    1101    201408110620    Technology and Computing    Internet Technology 1   20%
e-12    1101    201408110705    Technology and Computing    Antivirus Software  1   20%
e-12    1107    201408110510    Business    Advertising 1   12.5%
e-12    1107    201408110520    Business    Marketing   7   87.5%
e-12    1109    201408110505    Technology and Computing    Web Search  1   100%
```

NOTE: At this point, the count is NOT necessary.

Is this even possible in Hive? How can I modify my count query (below) to output that last table?

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, DATETIMESTAMP, CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2, count(*) FROM temp_table GROUP BY CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2, DATETIMESTAMP, COL2, COL1 SORT BY COL2;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could count the col2 and category2 separately using two select statements and then use these in the main select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of to do this.  You could calculate the denominator in your percentage and join that back to the original data and then `SUM` and divide by the total.  Also, if you have access to [windowing functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) in Hive (I believe they shipped with 0.13), you could use an `OVER` and `PARTITION` statement in `SELECT` to avoid the join described in the first part.

**#1:**

```
select col2, cat1, cat2, datetimestamp
    ,(COUNT(cat2) / MAX(total_)) as perc
from (
    select n.col2, cat1, cat2, datetimestamp, x.total_
    from some_table as n
    JOIN (
        select col2, COUNT(col2) as total_
        from some_table
        group by col2
         ) x
    ON x.col2 = n.col2
     ) y
group by cat1, cat2, col2, datetimestamp
```

**#2:**

```
select col2, cat1, cat2, datetimestamp
    ,(COUNT(col2) / MAX(total)) as perc
from (
    select col2, cat1, cat2
        ,COUNT(cat1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2) as total
    from some_table
     ) x
group by cat1, cat2, col2, datetimestamp
```

Comment: I used sample #2. I encountered a problem regarding `datetimestamp`, so I added it to the inner select statement. As well, I multiplied `perc` by 100, so as to closer mimic the look of a percentage sign. Will my edits have any effect on accuracy? I tested your code on the sample data above - so far, so good.